# How Add checkout form in each product page in magento?

Tags: product, checkout, forms

I need to add the checout form on individual product page like this site

http://www.symbios.pk/nokia-lumia-925

No need to have cart or the default mangento checkout page, user will checkout for individual product, from the respective product page by filling all respective details.

Is it possible in magento.
other example is in snapshot attached.
[image]

Comment: You could go with a onepagecheckout(modules) solution and set the option not to use the cart and go directly to the onepagecheckout. This requires less development, you remove the rest of the navigation from the checkout page so the user has focus on the checkout. (Still requires two pages, but it is another perspective)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It would be a custom checkout page, which would contain everything from address, shipping method, and payment forms. As you can image, it involves too much to answer here.

Essentially, you would need to create a form (or forms) that would take the required information for a checkout and pass those values to your controller to put together a quote and convert it to an order. Google "how to create an order programmatically" and you'll see plenty of examples. Here's one: http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/.

Alternatively, Inchoo has a guide on how to use the `'checkout/type_onepage'` class, which seems to simply thing a lot. I've never used it, though. http://inchoo.net/magento/magentos-onepage-checkout-in-a-nutshell/

Another method I could think of is directing the customer to the checkout page with a click of a button.. Instead of "add to cart", you would place "checkout" on the product page, which directs the customer to a custom controller action that will create a quote with that product and start the checkout process.